# Node.js: Need an "exit" command opposite to "node ." or "node index.js"

Tags: node.js

Easy(ish) question. In the terminal, I can start the node server by navigating to the node.js directory `C:/Code/Snickers` and running `node .`.

I need the command that does the opposite. I want to be able to navigate to the node.js directory `C:/Code/Snickers` and run `node stop/cancel/end/exit/cookie` to stop the server.

Yes, CTRL+C accomplishes this, but that only works if I have the terminal open. What if I want to ssh into that computer from another system to start the server? I could accomplish this on Windows by running `taskkill /F /IM node.exe` but this is too powerful. I might have another node server going in `C:/Code/MilkyWay` and I hate to shut it down as well. I could also use `taskkill /F /pid MY_PID_NUMBER`, but I don't want to have to look up the PID every single time.

My ultimate goal is to modularize this into a file, `start-snicker.sh` that I hope looks a little like this...

```
*****start-snicker.sh***** //Change directory, reset code to master, kill node, restart node.
cd C:/Code/Snicker && git reset --hard && node STOP/CANCEL/EXIT/CODE HERE && node .
```

I can then call this script remotely from anywhere:

```
ssh admin@123.456.7.89 -p 22 'cd "C:/Program Files/Git" && git-bash "C:/Code/start-snicker.sh"'
```

This already works, but start-snicker.js has this wrinkle of duplicating the node process each time. Without the exit code, I end up with multiple instances of snicker open.

Comment: process manager and SSH into the machine? (PM2 + SSH)

Comment: @BGPHiJACK can you explain that a little more? What about the process manager?

Comment: You run your Node.JS through the process manager, and you can close them by name you've maybe assigned via DB/etc and complete this with a few commands via SH.